# Unable to Display Youtube in Popup on window onload

Tags: magnific-popup

Used the below jQuery code but unable to replicate in local, need your help please!!!

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.popup-youtube').magnificPopup({
        type: 'iframe'
        iframe: {
            markup: '<div class="mfp-iframe-scaler">'+
                '<div class="mfp-close"></div>'+
                    '<iframe class="mfp-iframe" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'+
                 '</div>', 
            patterns: {
                youtube: {
                  index: 'youtube.com/', 
                  id: 'v=V0h-Qjiyc24', 
                  src: 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/%id%?autoplay=1' 
                }
            },
            srcAction: 'iframe_src', 
        }   
    });
});
```

Comment: Please provide more context. Please see the how to ask guide here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You need to use some webserver to make it work, because browsers tend to block some functionality due to security reasons.

Comment: what does "unable to replicate in local" mean? Not sure what you mean.